# Error al consumir API de Google Vision

Tags: java, api, junit

Antes de nada os explicaré qué estoy haciendo, estoy con la API de [Google Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/).

Tengo el siguiente código, el primero es mi `Resource`. La estructura que veis ahí es para hacerle una petición, el método que debería usarse y qué cosas deben modificarse en cada modelo (modelo-vista-controlador).

Me surgen varias dudas que debería corregir, pero por falta de información o no caer ahora mismo, no sé como hacerlo.

El código siguiente es el `Resource`, en el cual no entiendo los `cast` cuando estoy saltando (en las lineas con cast), de una clase a otra para establecer 2 atributos, además, me gustaría poner que en vez de devolverme una lista de `LabelAnnotation`, se pudiera una lista con las cadenas que hay dentro ¿es eso posible? ¿hay manera de quitar los `cast`?:

```
public class GoogleVisionResource {
    private final String uri_upload = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=------";
    public List<LabelAnnotation> uploadImgAndAnalyze(String uriIMG) {
        ClientResource cr = null;
        Envio envio = null;
        Respuesta respuesta = null;
        try {
            cr = new ClientResource(uri_upload);
            cr.setEntityBuffering(true); // Needed for using RESTlet from JUnit tests
            envio = new Envio();
            ((Feature) ((Request) envio.getRequests()).getFeatures()).setType("LABEL_DETECTION");
            ((Request) envio.getRequests()).getImage().getSource().setImageUri(uriIMG);
            respuesta = cr.post(envio,Respuesta.class);

        } catch (ResourceException re) {
            System.err.println("Error when adding the playlist: " + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
        }

        return  ((Response) respuesta.getResponses()).getLabelAnnotations();
    }
```

La cosa es, hago su controller tras tener el resource:

```
public class GoogleVisionUploadAnalaizeLabelsController extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GoogleVisionUploadAnalaizeLabelsController.class.getName());

    public GoogleVisionUploadAnalaizeLabelsController() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Request data
        String UrlImage = request.getParameter("UrlImage");
        // Analiza Imagen
        GoogleVisionResource lista = new GoogleVisionResource();
        List<LabelAnnotation> success = lista.uploadImgAndAnalyze(UrlImage);
        if (success != null) {
            request.setAttribute("Lista de etiquetas",success);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/GoogleVisionLabels.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            log.info("Lista de etiquetas no añadida, error al analizar la imagen");

        }
    }
}
```

Entonces hago su test en J unit Case:

```
String s="https://images.unsplash.com/photo1556767230449a4049ba05ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjQyMDV9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1191&q=80";
@Test
public void testUploadImgAndAnalyze() {
    GoogleVisionResource g = new GoogleVisionResource();
    List<LabelAnnotation> cr = g.uploadImgAndAnalyze(s);
    assertNotNull("List null",cr);

    System.out.println("Listing collections:");
    int i=1;
    for (LabelAnnotation c : cr) {
        System.out.println("L " + i+++" : " + c.getMid() + c.getScore());
    }

}
```

Y cuando lo ejecuto me dice:

> `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to .... envio.Request`

Y me da los errores en la línea del `Resource` en la que establezco el `LABEL_DETECTION` y luego en el test en la que declaro la lista de `labels` como `cr`. No entiendo el por qué de estos fallos ¿Podríais explicármelos?

Siento si mi escritura o forma de expresarme no son claros o faltan datos, he intentado dar la mayor cantidad de datos posibles, pero este tema no se me da demasiado bien.